# Can firefox be built behind a proxy without tunneling the build scripts?

Tags: firefox

On a windows box, behind a corporate proxy, already have a copy of the source following:

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/contributing/contribution_quickref.html#clone-the-sources

and

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/contributing/vcs/mercurial_bundles.html#mercurial-bundles

Build is done using Mozilla-Build:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/MozillaBuild

but fails due to proxy settings.

Does mozilla build have any proxy settings?

Comment: building Firefox should definitely be possible both behind proxy or completely offline. What is the specific error you're stumbling upon?

Comment: @Dexter setting the proxy settings in mozilla-build did it

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla build comes with mysis that can be configured to use env vars. On a windows box, in `[OS drive]:/Users/<user>/.bash_profile` add (create if not created):

```
# proxy settings
export HTTP_PROXY="username:password@proxy.server.address:port"
export HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
export http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
export https_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
```

Then reload: `source .bash_profile` . The above commands can be run from mysis.